# Использование неопределенного типа

Tags: c++, классы

Пишу абстрактный класс символьного дифференцирования и возникла проблема с объявлением классов sin и cos, если сначала объявляю cos, то не могу использовать sin в методе diff, если сначала объявляю sin, то не могу использовать cos. Ошибка: использование неопределенного типа "Sin"
Как решить эту проблему?

```
class Cos : public Expression
{
private:
    Expression *d1;
public:
    friend class Sin;
    Cos(Expression *L1) : d1(L1) {}
    Expression *diff()
    {
        return new Mul(new Sin(d1), d1->diff());
    }
    void print(){}
};
class Sin : public Expression
{
private:
    Expression *d1;
public:
    friend class Cos;
    Sin(Expression *L1): d1(L1) {}
    Expression *diff()
    {
        return new Mul(new Cos(d1), d1->diff());
    }
    void print(){}
};
```

Comment: `friend class Sin;`  и `friend class Cos;` не нужны в данном примере.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В определении функций `diff` требуется завершенный класс, раз уж вы используете его конструктор. Так что вы должны в объявлениях классов только объявить функции-члены `diff`, а вот определять их (писать тело) - вне классов.

Типа

```
class Cos : public Expression
{
private:
    Expression *d1;
public:
    friend class Sin;
    Cos(Expression *L1) : d1(L1) {}
    Expression *diff();
    void print(){}
};
```

Потом - такой же `Sin`, а уж только потом, вне классов, писать

```
Expression *Cos::diff()
{
    return new Mul(new Sin(d1), d1->diff());
}
```